# Facebook API Upload Video by URL to Media Library

Tags: python, facebook

We have been searching for weeks but can't figure out how to upload videos or images with the API to the Media Library.

Eventually we need a video id generated by the upload API to use in our ad creative.

[image]

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-image#Creating (says you have to upload a file though, doesn't mention upload from a URL), https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/advideo/v13.0

Comment: did you able to find out?

Comment: @Rose yes, see OkkeM answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a call to the advideos endpoint like so:

```
params = {
            'file_url': YOUR_URL,
            'access_token': YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN
        }
url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v13.0/{act_xxxxxxxxxx}/advideos"
r = requests.post(url, params)
response = r.json()
```